# Trivial jetpack compose android studio

Tags: android-studio

Estoy intentando que cada vez que pulses la respuesta de una pregunta, te aparezca rojo si es incorrecta, y verde si es la correcta. He conseguido que se haga pero solo me lo aplica a la última pregunta, en las 19 restantes NO. Es un trivial de preguntas, tengo la pantalla de inicio, y esta te lleva a la pantalla de las preguntas cuando le das al botón jugar. Son 20 preguntas. Hice este código para ver si me cambiaba al hacer click en el botón el color de la respuesta. Si es la correcta se cambia a verde, si es la falsa se cambia a rojo. El problema es que solo em lo aplica a la pregunta 20. El resto siguen normal, no cambia el color.
GameScreen :

```
val String.color
    get() = Color(parseColor(this))


@Composable
fun TrivialGameScreen(
    question: Question,
    onOptionSelected: (String) -> Unit
) {
    var selectedAnswer by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(text = question.text, modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
        question.answers.forEach { answer ->
            val isSelected = selectedAnswer == answer
            val backgroundColor = if (isSelected) {
                if (answer == question.correctAnswer) {
                    Color.Green
                } else {
                    Color.Red
                }
            } else {
                Color.Transparent
            }

            Button(
                onClick = {
                    selectedAnswer = answer
                    onOptionSelected(answer)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .background(color = backgroundColor)
            ) {
                Text(text = answer, color = Color.Black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity :

```
@Composable
fun TrivialGameApp(navController: NavController) {
    val trivialGame = remember { TrivialGame() }
    val questions = trivialGame.questions
    var currentQuestionIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val question = questions[currentQuestionIndex]

    TrivialGameScreen(
        question,
        onOptionSelected = { selectedAnswer ->
            if (trivialGame.answerQuestion(selectedAnswer)) {
                // Respuesta correcta
            } else {
                // Respuesta incorrecta
            }

            if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.size - 1) {
                // Avanzar a la siguiente pregunta
                currentQuestionIndex++
            } else {
                // Fin del juego
            }
        }

    )
}
```